# spring security error Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: s

Tags: oauth-2.0

Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "#authentication.principal.username + '님'" (template: "test/fragments/nav" - line 10, col 57)

-->

```
    <!--        <a th:if="${#authentication.isAuthenticated()}" th:text="${#authentication.principal.username + '님'}"></a>-->
```

I tried both

It's displayed well when logged in, but an error appears when you log out

Comment: <!--        <a th:if="${#authentication.principal == null}" th:text="'게스트'"></a>-->
        <!--        <a th:if="${#authentication.isAuthenticated()}" th:text="${#authentication.principal.username + '님'}"></a>-->

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.